# Where does this conclusion come from?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 6 p. 394:

[image: img]

The part of concern is underlined in red.  How did they reach that conclusion?

Comment: In general, if we have $n$ people at a round table, we can arrange them in $(n-1)!$ ways if we consider arrangements the same if we can rotate one layout to get to the other. Think of it like a dial on a safe: you can have the arrow pointing at $n$ different numbers but the dial is still the same

Comment: The Q is poorly stated, as the Q can only be understood from the solution. At my kitchen table the answer is 24 because no one in the seat  nearest the microwave would consider the seating arrangement to be the same if they were moved to another chair. The answer shows that we are to call two arrangements "the same" if a rotation turns one into the other. But  the Q as written might  be about my kitchen table.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, I agree!  The Q is a bit hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

As per @WaveX's answer, there are `4!` possible arrangements.  However `4` of them are just the same arrangements rotated at different angle, so we are left with `4!/4` arrangements that are not the rotations of another one.